# Highstock doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

i have this code that works in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B2jan/

But, when i put the SAME code to my website it doesn't work. Here i put the simple code:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/datepicker/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1,
                inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

             series: [{
     name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
     data: [
         [1364463576000, 46906],
         [1364463578000, 50379],
         [1364463580000, 33733],
         [1364463582000, 5612],
         [1364463981000, 14213],
         [1364464007000, 11208],
         [1364490137000, 38047],
         [1364665254000, 14964],
         [1364665256000, 11443],
         [1364665257000, 9005],
         [1364665259000, 5283],
         [1364665260000, 1731]
     ],
     marker: {
         enabled: true,
         radius: 3
     },
     shadow: true,
     tooltip: {
         valueDecimals: 2
     }
 }]
        });


</script>
```

Is a copy-paste of jsfiddle, i don't undertand why don't work.

Thanks!

EDITED:

I put the files on a host of internet and a localhost using Xammp, but is the same result.

Comment: Check the console (F12) for errors.

Comment: Make sure you have the req. jQuery library (1.9.1) like you have in your Fiddle.

Comment: This quetsion should have been tagged under javascript, or jquery.

Comment: Yes, i use the jquery library to do other scripts and works correctly. Also, i try change "datepicker/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" to "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js", but is the same result...

Comment: No errors, only a white web :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like you have made a change to the code and it is not a direct copy and paste. Did you change anything?

EDIT: Ahhhhhh, I spotted it, you were not copying the final closing tags of the Chart! :)

```
});
```

Look at the end of your code.

This works for me.

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1,
                inputEnabled: $('#container').width() > 480
            },

            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },

             series: [{
     name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
     data: [
         [1364463576000, 46906],
         [1364463578000, 50379],
         [1364463580000, 33733],
         [1364463582000, 5612],
         [1364463981000, 14213],
         [1364464007000, 11208],
         [1364490137000, 38047],
         [1364665254000, 14964],
         [1364665256000, 11443],
         [1364665257000, 9005],
         [1364665259000, 5283],
         [1364665260000, 1731]
     ],
     marker: {
         enabled: true,
         radius: 3
     },
     shadow: true,
     tooltip: {
         valueDecimals: 2
     }
 }]
        });

});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add jQuery Library that JSFiddle is using.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ensure it is linked before your other scripts so they know what your reference of $ (jQuery) is.